# I deleted my res folder by mistake

Tags: android, apk, decompiling

I deleted my res folder by mistake! Is there any way to recover it from my `apk` file in `/bin`? Is there an option to make deleted files be sent to somewhat like a Recycle Bin in Eclipse?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing that copy apk file from bin folder and apply this steps on it [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file/6081365#6081365)

This might be solved your problem..

Answer (score 2):

Please check Eclipse Help : [Restoring deleted resources from local history](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-87b.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use APKtool

The link is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)

Next time, do some backups...

Comment: Or configure a `Subversion` or `Git` repositority. This way you'll never lose your data this way.